# Design support for templated UserControl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, user-controls, designer

I have created a real simple templated UserControl using the following tutorial:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6(VS.80).aspx

I can now add this control to my mvc 2.0 application using:

```
<components:Box BoxType="Help" Title="Content Title" runat="server">
    <Content>
        <%: Html.TextBox("test") %>
        This is my awesome content!<br />
        <b>Test</b>
    </Content>
</components:Box>
```

However, when I go to the designer, I get an exception: 
Type 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not have a public property named 'Content'.

How can I fix this? I don't even need to use the drag-and-drop designer, just rendering the control will do fine.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to go here http://www.asp.net/mvc/ and read just about everything you can about MVC.

Comment: very Weird...i am having the same problem. it works when i use it in page (aspx) but the problem still exists when i use it inside user control (ascx).

Answer (score -1):

The article you read is about ASP.NET WebForms and this won't work in ASP.NET MVC. It is safe to say you can ditch your work and start over.

Create a Partial View or Html Helper for reusable content in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although I think you are wrong. I have tested it and it does work, except when adding code like the TextBox helper, because then it throws the exception.

Comment: ok then, continue on your path of WebForms style user controls with "runat=server" attribute in MVC world;)